# Batch runs correctly on third attempt but not in task manager at all

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, exe

I have read through various answers here and tried a few bits but with no luck.

My issue is with by script "log_copy_script.cmd", I have a few subroutines within it but one is acting very odd. The script is meant to get todays date, subtract 1 year and then initiate a deletion of a folder dated 1 year ago. It sometimes works. In fact if I run it via command line it will first try to delete a folder named nothing "", then it will try just the month and day "MMDD", then a third time it will do it correctly "YYYYMMDD". Any further subsequent times will be successful, as if something is cached.

Also when I run this via Windows Task Scheduler it will run and log to my log file but every single time it will attempt to delete "" blank.

Does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks. :-/

```
REM Get IP and Vol Name from file, define variables
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:/SystemHealthScripts/ip_address.txt) do set IP_ADDRESS=%%x
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:/SystemHealthScripts/vol_name.txt) do set VOL_NAME=%%x
set MAINDIR="\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%"
set SUBDIR="\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%\%LOG_DATE%"
set LOGFILE="\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%\log.txt"

if [%1]==[delete_oldest] (

  REM Format date
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set month=%%b&set year=%%c&set day=%%a
  set LOG_DATE=%year%%month%%day%

  set /A "DEL_YEAR=year-1"
  set DEL_DATE=%DEL_YEAR%%month%%day%

  REM Basic validation (Greater than or equal to 20160101 then valid date)
  if [%DEL_DATE%] GEQ [20160101] (
    call echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: Deleting date '%DEL_DATE%' started" >> %LOGFILE%
    call rmdir /s /q %MAINDIR%\%DEL_DATE%
    call echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: Deleting date '%DEL_DATE%' finished" >> %LOGFILE%

  ) else (
    call echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: ERROR in deleting date '%DEL_DATE%', validation not met!" >> %LOGFILE%
  )
)
```

Comment: Maybe I should point out that this script can be called at the same time for different reasons. I am use to Java and running instances, maybe this isn't like that? maybe my routines need seperate script files?

Comment: @magoo provides a great description of your problem but you could alleviate the problem by creating a function instead of using the IF block.  You could create a label named `:delete_oldest` and instead of the IF command you could just use the CALL command with the input parameter. `CALL :%~1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not assigning characters that have significance to `cmd` to your variables, you should be safe to insert a line `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of your scipt (first line).

With any code block (parenthesised code), the block is parsed first - and part of the parsing procedure is to replace **ANY** `%var%` variable with its then-current value. Since you assign for instance `month` within a code-block, then its value on the first run is *nothing* - with the `setlocal` absent, the value of `month` on the first run will be used as its initial value on the second, and so on.

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` does two things. First, when the batch ends, the environment is restored to its original setting. All of the changes are backed out, so any values assigned or altered in any run are "reset".

The second thing it does is to allow the syntax `!var!` to access the value of the variable *as it changes within the block* (normally as a result of a `for` loop, but also as a result of `if/else` operations).

So - add the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and replace *any* variable whose value changes within a block from `%var%` to `!var!`

This is known as "delayed expansion" - there are hundreds of items on SO on the subject. Use `search` for many, many, many examples.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very detailed responce. I shall go down to the lab now and make the changes. I have not seen this issue in other languages like Java etc. I am guessing global variables in most other languages already parse the code blocks first so I would never encounter this issue.

Comment: These changes worked perfectly. Infact it looks like it has solved some of my other issuse too! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach which takes out using any delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
REM Get IP and Vol Name from file, define variables
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("C:\SystemHealthScripts\ip_address.txt") do set "IP_ADDRESS=%%x"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("C:\SystemHealthScripts\vol_name.txt") do set "VOL_NAME=%%x"
set "MAINDIR=\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%"
set "SUBDIR=\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%\%LOG_DATE%"
set "LOGFILE=\\%IP_ADDRESS%%VOL_NAME%\log.txt"

if "%1"=="delete_oldest" CALL :delete_oldest

GOTO :EOF

:delete_oldest
REM Format date
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
    set "month=%%b"
    set "year=%%c"
    set "day=%%a"
)
set "LOG_DATE=%year%%month%%day%"

set /A "DEL_YEAR=year-1"
set "DEL_DATE=%DEL_YEAR%%month%%day%"

REM Basic validation (Greater than or equal to 20160101 then valid date)
if %DEL_DATE% GEQ 20160101 (
    echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: Deleting date '%DEL_DATE%' started" >> "%LOGFILE%"
    rmdir /s /q "%MAINDIR%\%DEL_DATE%"
    echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: Deleting date '%DEL_DATE%' finished" >> "%LOGFILE%"

) else (
    echo "%LOG_DATE% %LOG_TIME%: ERROR in deleting date '%DEL_DATE%', validation not met!" >> "%LOGFILE%"
)
```

Comment: Brill thanks! It's my first time for a long time writing a windows script, it's quite different to BASH. I'll play with your changes thanks.